# Sqlite error near "dasani2": syntax error

Tags: c#, sqlite

i am creating my first app with databases and i get an error :
 `SQLite error near "dasani2": syntax error`
,here is my db structure and first row :

```
id    name     lastname   username   password
1     first    second     dasani     dasani2
```

and here is my program code:

```
SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
        try
        {
            sqliteCon.Open();
            string Query = "select * from Users where username='" + Vartotojas.Text.Trim() + "'and password'" + Slaptazodis.Text.Trim() + "'";
            SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqliteCon);

            createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SQLiteDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
        }
```

Comment: Some good database practices: get used with [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.parameters(v=vs.80).aspx) - avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and handles arbitrary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the = sign:

```
... "'and password = '" + Slaptazodis.Text.Trim() + "'";
```

Side note: You shouldn't store your passwords in plain text.

Comment: yes,i need to use hashing,but now i`m only learning how everything works

Answer (score 0):

You missed the = symbol in password column

```
password='"...
```

and  it's not a insert query , It's a select query , So you don't need this below  line

```
        createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```